# models.CharField max_length less in django admin page

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model class with following field

```
aliases = models.CharField(max_length=500,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
```

Now, when I try to edit this on Django admin page its maxlength is `20`

```
<input class="vTextField" id="id_alias" maxlength="20" name="alias" type="text" value="ABCD,AAA">
```

I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/)

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'max_length':'40'})}
    }

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

import appropriate classes -- in this case:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models
```